# macOS vim locale different than shell

Tags: python, macos, shell, vim, encoding

In my macOS environment, my locale environment variables include an encoding

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

However, if I open vim then run locale, the encoding is missing!

```
:!locale

LANG="en_US"
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_ALL="en_US"

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

This causes a problem when running python programs from vim

```
return io.open(self.dotenv_path)
    E   LookupError: unknown encoding:
```

Looking for ideas on how to fix vim's behavior so that it no longer strips the encoding information from the environment

Comment: The shell in which `:!locale` is executed is not the same shell as the one in which you started Vim. Can you tell us where and how you set your locale? Also the output of `:set shell?` and `:set shellcmdflag?`.

Comment: `shell=/bin/bash` `shellcmdflag=-c`

Comment: locale is set by my terminal emulator (iTerm2) using its "Set locale variables automatically" preference. I tried disabling this preference in favor of setting the locale environment variables in my `$HOME/.bashrc` instead, but I get the same result. If it run `locale` in a new bash shell as vim is configured to do e.g. `/bin/bash -c locale`, the locale has the expected values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregard, it looks like I had some settings in vimrc that were clobbering the environment settings. Everything is OK once I remove the following from vimrc

```
try
  lang en_US
catch
endtry
```